# Launching network settings pane in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way to open the "Networks" pane programmatically from a Metro app in Windows 8?

I know that the Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane class will let you open the settings pane (which will have a button to open the networks pane at the bottom), but for my application I'd really like to open directly to the Networks pane.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined this a bit and it seems you cannot access the actual Network pane from a Metro app. The pane is part of the Explorer.exe which isn't wrapped nor accessible from any framework library on the platform. Explorer.exe is a Win32 executable.

You can see which Win32 and COM types are available from Metro http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that was the conclusion I reached as well.  Appreciate you looking into it, and the link contains some really useful info.